# Retrieve previous fytd start date and end date based on yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have searched and tried various query but keep getting stuck. Would really appreciate help with this. Could anyone suggest how to retrieve the start of previous 2 financial ytd based on date on yyyymmdd format?

I have a daily report where if date is yyyymmdd then I would like to retrieve the last 2 financial year start date. For example if date is 20180612 then I'ld like to get dates from 20160701.

Comment: What sql-server version did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @fytd = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(yyyy, @daily) - 2, 7, 1 ),112);--2016-01-01
SET @fytd = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(yyyy, @daily) - 1, 7, 1 ),112);--2017-07-01
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I've never used Datefromparts before and definitely will be using from now on.

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like

```
declare @daily varchar(100)= '20180403', @fytd varchar(100), @fytd2 varchar(100);
SELECT 
    @fytd = 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, 6,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @daily)), 0)), 112),
    @fytd2= -- to get previous FYTD just -1 from the result of DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @daily))
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, 6,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @daily))-1, 0)), 112)


select @fytd,  @fytd2
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/LSF24169)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much! this was also very helpful and gave me the right results